# how to pass @email without getting it entered by user from login page. and it will show in masterpage

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to parse the user `already signed-up` email-address into my master page without asking user to enter it from login page. From the  `AuthenticateUser` function, I'm able to parse username into my my master page correctly by "string loginName " because I get it by user key in through log in module. Just don't know how to get email since user do not key in.

```
     protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (AuthenticateUser(txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Text))
            {
                // Create the authentication cookie and redirect the user to welcome page
                FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(txtUserName.Text, chkBoxRememberMe.Checked);

                 Response.Redirect("homePage.aspx"); 
            }
            else
            {                     
                lblMessage.Text = "Invalid UserName and/or password";
            }
        }

        private bool AuthenticateUser(string username, string password)
        {
            // ConfigurationManager class is in System.Configuration namespace
            string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
            // SqlConnection is in System.Data.SqlClient namespace



            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
            {
                string loginEmail = "";
                string loginName = "";

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spAuthenticateUser", con);
               // SqlDataReader reader;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;       

                // FormsAuthentication is in System.Web.Security
                string EncryptedPassword = FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(password, "SHA1");
                // SqlParameter is in System.Data namespace
                SqlParameter paramUsername = new SqlParameter("@UserName", username);
                SqlParameter paramPassword = new SqlParameter("@Password", EncryptedPassword);
                //SqlParameter paramEmail = cmd.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
                //SqlParameter paramEmail = new SqlParameter("@Email", SqlDbType.NVarChar);                    

                cmd.Parameters.Add(paramUsername);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(paramPassword);
               // cmd.Parameters.Add(paramEmail);    

                loginName = paramUsername.ToString();
               // loginEmail = paramEmail.ToString();
                con.Open();                 

              //  reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                int ReturnCode = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                Session["Status"] = "Login";
                Session["LoginName"] = username;
                Session["LoginEmail"] = loginEmail;
                return ReturnCode == 1;                    
            }
        }
```

database:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblUsers] (
    [Id]       INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [UserName] NVARCHAR (100) NULL,
    [Password] NVARCHAR (400) NULL,
    [Email]    NVARCHAR (200) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);




stored procedure : spAuthenticateUser

CREATE Procedure spAuthenticateUser
@UserName nvarchar(100),
@Password nvarchar(400)

as
Begin
 Declare @Count int

 Select @Count = COUNT(UserName) from tblUsers
 where [UserName] = @UserName and [Password] = @Password 
 if(@Count = 1)
 Begin
  Select 1 as ReturnCode
 End
 Else
 Begin
  Select -1 as ReturnCode
 End
End*
```

Answer (score 0):

When someone log into your website, you can write his ID in the session.

So in your log in you have something like that

```
Select * from [user] where password=@password and email=@email
```

Here you will take the User.ID and write it in the session so you will know which user is in your website.

```
Session["__UserID"] = row["ID"]// row from previous query.
```

Now when you need some data for the logged user you just take from the session his ID and make a query to fetch the data.

P.S If you need to store more data in the session on log in, it is best practise to create class and write it in the session. In this class you will have UserID, UserName or whatever you want as properties.